# Conditioning uniform distribution on subset of support gives uniform distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, uniform-distribution

$\newcommand{\vZ}{\boldsymbol{\mathbf{Z}}}$I am reading [this](http://web.tecnico.ulisboa.pt/~mcasquilho/CD_Casquilho/MC_Flury_ar.pdf) paper regarding a *simple* proof of why [rejection sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling) works. I managed to understand the proof of Lemma 1, but I am struggling with the other two. The second lemma says:

> Suppose the $m$-dimensional random variable $\mathbf{Z}$ has a uniform distribution in $A\subset\mathbb{R}^m$, where $0<V(A)<\infty$. Let $B\subset A, V(B) > 0$. Then the conditional distribution of $\mathbf{Z}$, given $\mathbf{Z}\in B$ is uniform in $B$.

---

The author says the proof is obvious, but I don't see how. Here is my attempt:

**Proof**

First of all, $\vZ$ has a uniform distribution on $A$ means
$$
\newcommand{\vZ}{\boldsymbol{\mathbf{Z}}}
\begin{equation}
p(\vZ) = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{V(A)} & \text{if } \vZ\in A\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
$$
Now we want to find the conditional distribution of $\vZ$ given that $\vZ\in B$.
$$
\begin{align}
    p(\vZ\mid \vZ\in B) = \frac{p(\vZ, \vZ\in B)}{p(\vZ\in B)}
\end{align}
$$
We can find the denominator as 
$$p(\vZ\in B) = \int_B p(\vZ) dA = \int_B \frac{1}{V(A)} dA = \frac{1}{V(A)}\int_B dA = \frac{V(B)}{V(A)}$$

At this point, I only need to find an expression for the numerator, however I since we know $\vZ\in B$, then certainly 
$$p(\vZ, \vZ\in B) = p(\vZ\in B) = \frac{V(B)}{V(A)}$$
so that we get 
$$p(\vZ \mid \vZ\in B) = \frac{V(B)}{V(A)} \times \frac{V(A)}{V(B)} = 1$$
However this is not the definition of being uniform in $B$. We should rather obtain something like:

$$
\begin{equation}
p(\vZ\mid \vZ\in B) = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{V(B)} & \text{if } \vZ\in B\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
$$

Comment: the key error is in the line $p(Z, Z\in B) = p(Z\in B)$.  The RHS is certainly a probability, but the LHS is not.  (Or, as a probability, its value is $0$.)  PDFs can be tricky because they are not probabilities, but rather, densities.  See if [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability_distribution) helps...

Comment: Do you mind telling me how I should change it?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an equivalent definition of being uniformly distributed:

> $Z$ is uniform on $A$ if for any (measurable) subset $E\subset A$,  $$P(Z\in E)=V(E)/V(A).$$

To verify that $Z$ conditioned on $Z\in B$ is uniform on $B$, it therefore suffices to show that for any measurable $E\subset B$, that $P(Z\in E|Z\in B)=V(E)/V(B)$. Now
$$
P(Z\in E|Z\in B)=\frac{P(Z\in E\cap Z\in B)}{P(Z\in B)}=\frac{P(Z\in E)}{P(Z\in B)}=\frac{V(E)/V(A)}{V(B)/V(A)}=\frac{V(E)}{V(B)}.
$$